# Inverse of a product of real functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inverse

Given $F(x) = L(x)G(x)$, with $L$ and $G$ real function strictly greater than zero. Suppose that F and G are decreasing functions (so that $F^{-1}$ and $G^{-1}$ exists). What can we say about the inverse of $F$?

$$F^{-1}(y)$$

Do some representations of this type
$$F^{-1} = H  G^{-1}$$
exist, for some $H$? (and which would be the link between $L$ and $H$?) Please report more results as you can, even with stronger assumptions on what you want. Thanks.
$$$$
And last but not least, numerically speaking, is it a difficult problem? Suppose I can invert numerically $F$ and $G$, so that I can find $H$. Do I have some info about $L$? What can I do?

Comment: Do you mean to assume that $L^{-1}$ and $G^{-1}$ exist? Or are the assumptions as written the ones you are interested in?

Comment: @Chill2Macht It's indifferent. Can you say something with the only hypothesis of existence?

Comment: No I have no idea either way to be honest. I had the question in the other form, which is why I asked. Admittedly I should probably think about it more.